# Using fzf inside vim with double star completion

Tags: buffers, split, plugin-fzf, fzf

I wonder if it is possible to use fzf inside vim the same way it can be used on the command line. So, on the command line I can do `vim file**` and it will use fzf to search 'file'. I wonder if this is possible inside vim with `:e`/`:sp`/`:vsp`, so using it as `:e file**`.

vim by itself does support the option to search for a file with `:e **/file`, but it does not search the file "fuzzily" and cannot ignore `.gitignore`.

I am aware of fzf.vim `:Files` command, but you need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to open in a split and it isn't just a one-to-one replacing of the preferred command line functionality.